# What is the best way to add a listener to my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which extends DialogFragment and which need to notify other objects when its content changes.

The android fragment guide, state that the best way to do this is to require that the containing activity implements an specified interface and then cast the activity to that interface and call the method.

This does work, but it has the limitation that only the containing activity can listen for changes. What do I do if I want to be able to notify arbitrary objects?

I can't just take make a method which take a listener as argument, because the fragment may be re-constructed by Android behind my back. And I can't put the listener in a bundle, because I have no way of knowing if the class implement the listener can be persisted/serialized and I really don't all listener objects to be duplicated.

My fragment is used both in a popup, and as a normal fragment which is shown in the main view

Comment: Why don't you use the interface approach you mention above and in the activity send a broadcast to notify whoever you want to listen to that broadcast?

Comment: That might work, but it causes a tight coupling between the fragment and the Activity. I don't want my fragment to require special  broadcast code in all Activities which include my fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [EventBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Basically you can register to an event from anywhere and send events from anywhere. Events are plain Pojos which can contain any variables or other objects. 
This makes the whole communication between Activities, Fragments and so on so much easier.

Comment: I will take a look at it. But it seems like a heavy solution which require lot's of code, just to do a 1:1 communication.

Comment: It does indeed require only very little code. Couple of lines and you're good.

Comment: That's still more then the single line I would like it to require.  But I guess a couple of lines are not that bad. And the root cause of my problem is really that the original "developers" wrote the entire app as a single Activity.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate event bus solution is to use Square's [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Or you can try the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager is unfortunately only available through the support-v4 compatibility library.

Answer (score 0):

Make and interface, which suports callbacks, for example:

```
interface IListener{  
    public void onEventRaised(object arguments);  
}
```

Then make a static class which has a List of listeners and calls them when you raise the event, for example:

```
    public static class AppListenerDispatcher{
        private static List<IListener> listeners; //make add and remove methods  

        public static void raiseMyEvent(object arguments){
           for (IListener listener: listeners)
             listener.onEventRaised(arguments);
        }
    }
```

And now you just need to implement this interface in the coresponding class that will listen for this event and add it to the list. Then you can call the `AppListenerDispatcher.raiseMyEvent(arguments)` anywhere and all the listeners in the list will do their corresponding work.